# getting back array of object data in a specific format from a mongoose query

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

With Mongoose and express, while retrieving a friends list,

I'm getting back data I don't need in a format that I need simplified

1. how do I hide _id and status in the friends sub document?
2. I want an array of objects that's populating the id fields of each object rather than everything else including the _id and status from the schema.

eg.

```
var friends = [{firstName: "User 1", lastName: "User 1", username: "user1"}, {firstName: "User 2", lastName: "User 2", username: "user2"}]
```

currently it looks like this

```html
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  friends: [
    { 
      id: 
        { 
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
          status: Number 
        }
    }
  ]
});

app.get('/getFriends', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, 'friends')
 .populate({
   path: 'friends.id',
  model: 'User',
  select: 'username firstName lastName -_id'
 })
 .exec(function(err, friends) {
   res.json(friends);
 }) 
})

friends: [ 
  { 
    id: [Object], 
    status: 2, 
    _id: 590bbb88858367c9bb07776e 
  },
  { 
    id: [Object], 
    status: 2, 
    _id: 590bbb95858367c9bb07776f 
   }
]

id Object
firstName: "User 1", lastName: "User 1", username: "user1"
```

Answer (score 0):

use the select function to select only the properties that you want

```
.select('firstName lastName username').exec(function(err, friends) {
      res.json(friends);
})
```

or use a combination of `map` and `delete` to remove the key/value pairs

```js
var friends = [{
    id: 1,
    status: 2,
    _id: 590 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    status: 2,
    _id: 590 
  }
];

friends = friends.map(function(v) {
 delete(v._id);
 return v;
});

console.log(friends);
```